# I phone 4 and Imac Icloud text issue

Tags: icloud

I have an imac and most people that text me on my iphone 4 comes through on my imac via icloud. It's still working well for all my contacts except one and it comes up red. So when i recieve texts from this person on my phone I cannot see it or respond on my imac, and if I try to text them on my Imac it shows undeliverable?? Help

Comment: actually it's a macbook pro, not imac

Answer (score 1):

If their name at the top of the message window shows in red, 'apple' thinks it's an sms-only number.

Check & if necessary re-select their proper connection details from that red name
[becomes a drop-menu if you click it - down arrow to the right of the name]
Will turn blue when it connects successfully, or stay red if it **is** only SMS-capable.